# custom permalinks for variable wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

i have url like `/company-page/?comp_id=84`where company id getting from database and i what rewrite this url as

```
/company-page/testcompany
```

Comment: It's very difficult to understand what you are asking for. Do you have an existing page and you want the URL rewritten? Or do need dynamic results pages to have static URLs? Explain more what you are trying to accomplish and we may be more helpful.

Comment: hey men "company-page" is your custom post type or page or used any plugin? please specify more details.

Comment: @renishkhunt no company is not a custom post type,ii is recorded in db as record,

Comment: @Brian Johnson i just want when user enter /company-page/?comp_id=84 load page with url like /company-page/testcompany  not with the company id it self..

Answer (score 1):

The default permalink type is "Ugly", it looks like: `http://example.com/?p=123`

The good news is that in WordPress you can change how your page URL looks to visitor by using "Pretty Permalinks", just go to your administration panel, then find `Settings` -> `Permalinks` and choose `Post name` (or `Custom Structure` and read carefully how you can name them).

**Please note:**

You **never, ever** put your site URL in the permalinks slot. You must use one of the structure tags, or a combination of tags only.

More details can be found [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks).

Answer (score 1):

You are going to want to create a template file for "company-page". Having a file named page-company-page.php uploaded to your theme folder should suffice. Copy the content from your theme's standard page.php file into it.

Then, remove the part that actually displays any of the post content. Replace it with this:

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['comp_id'])) { //Make sure there IS a value
                                $company_id = $_GET['comp_id']; 

                                $args = array (
                                            'posts_per_page' => 1,
                                            'meta_query' => array(
                                                array(
                                                    'key'     => 'comp_id',
                                                    'value'   => $company_id,
                                                    'compare' => '='
                                                    )
                                                  )
                                               )

                             $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

                             $posts = $the_query->get_posts();

foreach($posts as $post)  { ?>

                                <script type="text/javascript"><!--
                                window.location = "<?php the_permalink(); ?>"
                                //--></script>


                      <?php } 
wp_reset_postdata(); 
} ?>
```

What this code does is checks for the company ID, then queries for the post that has that ID. Then there is a javaScript redirect to the actual post page, where normal pretty permalinks take over. Research that more if you don't understand how those work.

A couple notes:
- This solution assumes you aren't using /company-page/ as an archive list of all companies. With some modifications you could bring back that functionality, however.
- If there is more than one company with the same comp_id, the user will be redirected to the first one.